# Summing ordered samples

Tags: mathematical-statistics, python, central-limit-theorem, order-statistics

Let's pick a random number between 0 and 1 uniformly 1000 times and put the results in an array for example : [0.176,0.765,0.879,0.234,0.152,0.765,0.645,0.897,0.762,0.087...] and sort this sample from smallest to largest. 
Then repeat the experience n times and keep the n arrays. Finally make the sum of all the arrays and we have a big array for example : [3.7636,4.7362,8,87...]. 
Can someone help me and give me a mathematical explanation of why the CLT does not apply and why the distribution of the sum seems to be uniform between 0 and n and not normal the more n and the size of my samples increase ?

Here the histogram when I order my samples :
[image: ordered samples]

Histogram when I do not order my samples :
[image: normal samples]

My python code :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


sum1= np.asarray([0. for k in range(1000)])
for i in range(1000):
    sum1 = np.add(sum1, np.sort(np.asarray([np.random.random() for j in range (1000)])))

plt.hist(sum1,range(int(min(sum1)), int(max(sum1))))
plt.show()
```

Many thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The CLT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) makes a statement about what happens if you sum up many independent draws of *one* random variable: if you do this many times, the distribution of the sum will converge to normality.

What you are doing here is summing 1000 *different* variables. Each separate one is an order statistic from the uniform distribution, and each separate one has a different expectation: essentially, the $i$-th entry in each of your vectors of length 1000 has an expectation of about $\frac{i}{1000}$. And then, you are not repeating this experiment many times, but just a single time. The result is a single vector of length 1000, which is (almost, because of boundary issues) uniformly distributed.

Here is something where the CLT does give you what you expect. Do your experiment many times (I chose 200 replicates, and changed your 1000 to 100 to shorten runtimes), and in each case, only record the first entry of `sum1`. The result looks much more normal, and would look more so with more than 200 replicates:

[image: distribution]

```
first_entry = [0 for _ in range(200)]
for ii in range(len(first_entry)):
    sum1 = np.asarray([0. for k in range(100)])
    for i in range(100):
        sum1 = np.add(sum1, np.sort(np.asarray([np.random.random() for j in range(100)])))
    first_entry[ii] = sum1[0]
plt.hist(first_entry)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you ! I understand now why the CLT doesn't work. But I precisely want a uniform distribution from a sum of samples from uniform distributions and I do not exactly understand why "the i-th entry in each of your vectors of length 1000 has an expectation of about i/1000" and why it also works with an exponential distribution etc
Many thanks in advance

Comment: Since you pick 1000 points from the uniform distribution *and then order them*, the $i$-th data point will be at around $\frac{i}{1000}$. What do you mean by "**it** works with an exponential distribution"? What are you referring to?

Comment: If i replace the uniform distribution by an exponential distribution the sum looks like an exponential distribution too

Comment: That is not surprising to me. If you sample from any distribution and then order, the ordered samples will have separate expectations that look like the original distribution. If you then sum or average entry-wise, you recover the original distribution. This should work with any distribution. What other distribution of the averages would you expect?

Comment: I don't know what I was expected, sorry, but I wanted to be sure that I was recovering the original distribution and not just something similar. I didn't find a lot of things about the sum of ordered samples on the internet, maybe I don't have the right keywords. Thanks for your time I can't vote up your answers since I'm a recent user but it was useful for a statistic beginner like me.

Comment: Don't think of it as *summing ordered samples*. Look at each entry separately, like I did for the first one. This is an *order statistic*, and you can find information about the distribution of order statistics, e.g., from the uniform distribution. And then, in a second step, you take sums or averages of such order statistics, which is where the CLT kicks in again.